# Split Word document by specific page range

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I am new to stackoverflow and I have fair knowledge about vb.net. However I am stuck at something very simple

I want to split a word document using vb.net.

This is what I tried to split it and it works as I want it. This code splits the document page by page.

```
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim oWordApp As New Word.Application
        Dim oWordMainDoc As Word.Document
        Dim docSingle As Word.Document
        Dim rngPage As Word.Range
        Dim strNewFileName As String = ""

        Dim iCurrentPage As Integer, iPageCount As Integer

        oWordMainDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=TextBox1.Text, ReadOnly:=True)
        oWordMainDoc.ActiveWindow.View.Type = 3

        rngPage = oWordMainDoc.Range

        iCurrentPage = 1

        iPageCount = oWordMainDoc.Content.ComputeStatistics(2)

        Do Until iCurrentPage > iPageCount
            If iCurrentPage = iPageCount Then
                rngPage.End = oWordMainDoc.Range.End
            Else
                oWordApp.Selection.GoTo(1, 1, iCurrentPage + 1)
                rngPage.End = oWordApp.Selection.Start
            End If

            docSingle = oWordApp.Documents.Add

            rngPage.Copy()
            docSingle.Range.PasteAndFormat (19)
            docSingle.Range.Find.Execute(FindText:="^m", ReplaceWith:="")

            strNewFileName = Replace(oWordMainDoc.FullName, ".doc", "_" & iCurrentPage & "_.doc")

            docSingle.SaveAs (strNewFileName)
            iCurrentPage = iCurrentPage + 1
            docSingle.Close()
            rngPage.Collapse (0)
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

However I am trying to tweak it so that I can split it by a page range. For example. I want to extract page 3-7 from a 50 page document. But I am not unable to do so.

I **tried** the below but I am not able to get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim oWordApp As New Word.Application
    Dim oWordMainDoc As Word.Document
    Dim docSingle As Word.Document
    Dim rngPage As Word.Range
    Dim strNewFileName As String = ""

    Dim iCurrentPage As Integer, iPageCount As Integer, iLastPage As Integer

    oWordMainDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=TextBox1.Text, [ReadOnly]:=True)
    oWordMainDoc.ActiveWindow.View.Type = 3

    rngPage = oWordMainDoc.Range

    iCurrentPage = 3 'start page
    iLastPage = 7 'end page

    Dim diff As Integer = iLastPage - iCurrentPage

    If iCurrentPage = iPageCount Then
        rngPage.End = oWordMainDoc.Range.End
    Else
        'i think this should define the page range?
        oWordApp.Selection.GoTo(1, 1, iCurrentPage + diff)
        rngPage.End = oWordApp.Selection.Start
    End If

    docSingle = oWordApp.Documents.Add

    'this doesnt copy the desired pages
    rngPage.Copy()
    docSingle.Range.PasteAndFormat(19)
    docSingle.Range.Find.Execute(FindText:="^m", ReplaceWith:="")

    strNewFileName = Replace(oWordMainDoc.FullName, ".doc", "_" & iCurrentPage & "_.doc")

    docSingle.SaveAs(strNewFileName)
    docSingle.Close()
End Sub
```